# T doesn't implement std::fmt::Debug

Tags: struct

I'm trying to have a `Hash` variable stored in my struct. I have to pass `T` so I can call `T::Hash`. But when I use the struct in the method variable it throws an error.

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct Profile<T: Config> {
    pub my_hash: T::Hash
}
```

```
pub fn create(origin: OriginFor<T>, profile: Box<Profile<T>>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo  {
    let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    <Profiles<T>>::insert(&sender, profile);
    Self::deposit_event(Event::<T>::ProfileUpdate(sender));

    Ok(Pays::No.into())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `T` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
   --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:124:39
    |
124 |         pub fn create(origin: OriginFor<T>, profile: Box<Profile<T>>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo  {
    |                                             ^^^^^^^ `T` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Profile` more generic by not taking a `T` that's supposed to be a `Config` and instead just a generic `Hash` type, and then fixing the type to `T::Hash` on the function parameter instead. This way there's no issues deriving the `Debug` trait. Try this instead:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
pub struct Profile<Hash> {
    pub my_hash: Hash,
}

pub fn create(origin: OriginFor<T>, profile: Box<Profile<T::Hash>>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I suspect what's happening here is the `#[derive(RuntimeDebug)]` requiring `T` to also implement `Debug`. This is a [known issue in Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925), where type parameters are often forced to also implement the trait that you are `#[derive]`ing from.

Fortunately, in Substrate, you can prevent `T` from also deriving `Debug` here by using a special trait called `frame_support::pallet_prelude::RuntimeDebugNoBound`. It does essentially the same thing as `RuntimeDebug`, with the caveat where it leaves all type parameters untouched.